# Windows Service not working as expected

Tags: .net, service, windows-services

I have a windows service which polls a file location and when some required files are found, it sends out emails. This service has been Live for quite some time now and had been working well until last week when it went haywire.

There is a log maintained to capture the files which are moved into that location. As and when a file is moved to that location, an entry is made in the log file. Also, when the criteria is met and a mail is sent, there is an entry in the log file for that too saying that the mail has been sent. Similarly, entries are made upon starting or stopping the service.

Since last week, the service is not working properly. No mails are being sent. I checked the SMTP server, all is fine there(confirmed by SMTP team). I checked the logs and came to know that the entries are not getting logged. Even when files were moved to that location, it was not captured in the logs.

I am unable to think of any reason. I have tried restarting the service many times.

**EDIT1**

Further information:

The windows service is a FileWatcher based service.

**EDIT2**

All this time I had been using a shared path for polling the files. I tried using the same path on 3 different servers. Same result. Then I tried using a local path(a path on the F drive of the server) and it worked as expected. But I still need to be able to do it in a shared path. The only thing common all the while is that shared path!

Comment: sounds like a security issue, anybody change perms anywhere?

Comment: It's difficult to help with so few information. For example, what is the name of the service you are talking about. Do you have some error message somewhere, ...

Comment: No error messages have been logged. The name of the service is Email_Tool

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed your code then the problem is environmental. The biggest environmental factor is the user account permissions under which your Windows Service is running. If it is a domain account, is it still valid for IO to the disk ? If it is a local account, have the local account policies changed to prevent IO ? Can you check the effective permissions on the File System you are using to make sure the Windows Service execution account has the correct permissions ?

One last thing (not directly related to your question) I have written an identical utility for other purposes, so beware that FileSystemWatcher does not provide a guaranteed service; in some cases individual file notifications are converted into generic "some files changed" notifications, and it is not that reliable on a shared drive over a network. It would possibly be more reliable to use a polling Task because you could at least log any permission exceptions when you look for changes - at the moment I guess you simply dont get a notificaiton and you dont know why.